# change the color of textbox on pageload

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any way to change the color of the textbox which is defined as required in model. The color should appear when the page load not when the submit button is hit and anything fails.

I need this without assigning any extra class or id in the view. Is there any such property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put this rule on your css file :

```
input[type=text][data-val-required]{color:red /* or any other color */}
```

**Note:** IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified

for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @tereško there are no problem to redirect any one to a valid information. and this is not a valid reason to downvote the answer

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: @Ahmad: This is **perfectly** valid reason to downvote the answer. An answer is rated on usefulness. Linking to bad reference resources contributes against the question's usefulness. When you remove the link, I'm sure the downvotes will be lifted.